# Tool for suggesting possible parallelism

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is there any tool available which can find/suggest possible places in code which can be re-factored to use parallelism for improving performance.

Comment: Yes. It is profiler :) Find bottlenecks, ask question: can I speed it up by parallel computing? IF yes THAN go_for_it :)

Comment: Intel Advisor, http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-xe, claims to provide the sort of information you want and to operate with C#.  I've only used it to a limited extent with codes written in other languages so can't provide a cast-iron guarantee that it will do what you want but it should be worth a look.

Comment: Suitability analysis of intel-advisor-xe is what i was looking for. Thanks @HighPerformanceMark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to suggest places in code that can be optimised by parallelism or concurrency would be a very tough job to implement in to any static analyser. I don't know of any tool that can do this out-of-the-box.

As one of the commenters said, the best approach would be to read and gain a solid understanding of where parallelism or concurrency can help you and combine this with tools such as the Visual Studio profiler.

One tool which maybe of some interest to you is [JetBrains' Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). I don't belive it does what you require, but it is a great tool and who knows, what you require may be added in future releases?

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP's interest doesn't seem to be confined to static analysis only.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I mentioned the profiler which is a run-time tool. I though I would state that, as a static analysis problem it is a hard one. One I would happily swap what I am doing to work on...